# How to fix a node in a position using SpriteKit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have created a world using SpriteKit, containing a SKShapeNode. I'd like to tie it into the ceiling. The gravity and other stuff still have their effect on this shape, but it should hang from the ceiling. Like a lamp, or a rope.

My shape:

```
let shape = SKShapeNode(rectOfSize: CGSize(width: self.tamanhoQuadrado, height: self.tamanhoQuadrado))
```

When I add this:

```
shape.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: CGSize(width: self.tamanhoQuadrado, height: self.tamanhoQuadrado))
```

It falls to the ground. I haven't found a property that can ignore gravity.

Comment: btw, I tried using the joints, but cannot ignore gravity with skphisicsbody set...

Comment: I just cannot ignore gravity with phisicsbody, what specific do you want me to share?

Comment: use an edge-based body if it shouldn't move

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it!

```
//no gravity
shape.physicsBody!.affectedByGravity=false
//make it stay on it's place        
shape.physicsBody!.dynamic=false
```